# Where to find "delegate" and "datasource" method documentation for NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, datasource, delegates, nstableview

I'm looking for Apple documentation regarding the "delegate" and "datasource" methods for NSTableView.  They don't appear in the [NSTableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for some reason.  Any idea where I can look?  Here's an example of one of them:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
   setObjectValue:(id)object 
   forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
              row:(NSInteger)row;
```

**EDIT:** It appears they appear in the *NSTableView.h* file with comments, though that's a pain to browse through.  I'd prefer a more user-friendly doc format, if it's available.  :)

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this question.  It is a perfectly valid question and one that confused new folk regularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NSTableViewDataSource Protocol Reference and NSTableViewDelegate Protocol Reference contain what you're looking for. There are a number of links to these from the NSTableView Class Reference as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. For some reason, Apple documentation does not have a standardize way of linking to pages describing the delegate methods. In some cases, the delegate methods are included as a subheading in the class itself. In others, there are links to the delegate page in the sidebar. Sometimes the links are buried in the text. It's very frustrating.

Just a tip, the delegates are almost always referred and linked to in the "Overview" section of each class document page. If you can't find them in a logical place, look there.

If you need to search for the delegate methods, the protocol is almost always named in a standardized way with the class name followed by "delegate" or "datasource e.g. UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. You should follow that standard when naming delegates in your own code.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.  This is definitely info that seems to be missing.  None of my Obj-C or Cocoa books mention this convention either.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if you see a method some place in Xcode, and you want to know what it does, just hold command+option and double click on the method. That will take you to the documentation for that method.

Ultimately, that will lead you [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).